# how to pass listview row data into another existing form

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

i want to have 2 forms in which the first form has a button that will load up form2 in a dialog form. form2 will show a listview displaying the data of a student. now i need to extract the 1st index of the selected row. once i double click on the row, form2 would close and pass the data into a textbox in form1.

i have used the code below which closes my form1 and creates a new instance of form1 in form2.

from form2:

```
 private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  var cl = listView1.Items[listView1.FocusedItem.Index].SubItems[0].Text;
  Form1 wa= new Form1();
  wa.loadid(cl);
  wa.Show();
  this.Close();
 }
```

from form1:

```
 private void btnReq_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        Form2 f2= new Form2();
        f2.Show();
        this.Close();
 }
 public void loadid(String ms)
 {
  String newstring = ms;
  studentid.Text = newstring;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a **Dialog**, it makes it very easy:

This is Form1. You instantiate and open f2 as Dialog and then wait for its result.OK

```
private void Button1_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var f2 = new Form2();

    if (f2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
        studentId.Text = f2.SelectedStudentId;
    } else {
        studentId.Text = "Select a Student!!!!";
    }
}
```

This in Form2, where you have created your listview and a public property to expose:

```
 public string SelectedStudentId { get; set; }

 private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    var cl = listView1.Items[listView1.FocusedItem.Index].SubItems[0].Text;
    SelectedStudentId = cl;
    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; //will close this dialog (form2)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

In Form1 create a public variable like this:

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
    //New variable
    public static string StudentIDVal;
```

Then, change the button click on Form1 to be:

```
private void btnReq_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2= new Form2();
    f2.ShowDialog(); 
    studentid.Text = StudentIDVal;
}
```

Then, on Form2 on the item click you can simply have:

```
private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var cl = listView1.Items[listView1.FocusedItem.Index].SubItems[0].Text;
   Form1.StudentIDVal = cl.ToString();
   this.Close();
}
```