# C# - Pass data between two forms (Windows Forms Application)

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a project in C# Windows Form application, in my project i have 2 screens, 1 - ListView to show datas, 2 - Formulary to get information and put on ListView, the main issue is, pass the information from Form2 to Form1.

My logic:

- Get information from user on the Form2 and pass to other Class
- On Form1 get information from that other Class and add on ListView

The issue:

- Object kind `ListViewItem` return null

Form2: Get information from Form

```
    namespace Company
{
    public partial class Register : Form
    {
        EmployeeDAO employeeDAO = new EmployeeDAO();

        public Register()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.idEmployee = Convert.ToInt16(this.txtId.Text);
            employee.nameEmployee = this.txtName.Text;
            employeeDAO.insert(employee);

        }

    }
}
```

My class DAO to get information from Form2 and pass to Form1: (I get information and put a ListViewItem and return it)

```
namespace Company
{
    class EmployeeDAO
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();

        public void insert(Employee employee)
        {
            string id;
            string name;
            id = Convert.ToString(employee.idEmployee);
            name = employee.nameEmployee;
            String[] row = { id, name };
            item = new ListViewItem(row);
        }

        public ListViewItem read()
        {
            //This item are returning null
            return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Form1 to show datas on a ListView: (I get the ListViewItem object and Add to ListView)

```
namespace Company
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {

        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lstEmployee.View = View.Details;
            lstEmployee.FullRowSelect = true;
            lstEmployee.Columns.Add("ID", 150);
            lstEmployee.Columns.Add("Nome", 150);
            insert();
        }

        private void insert()
        {
            EmployeeDAO employeeDAO = new EmployeeDAO();
            ListViewItem item = employeeDAO.read();
            if (item == null)
            {
                //Always this block run
                MessageBox.Show("No Item");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Item");
                lstEmployee.Items.Add(item);
            }            
        }

        private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Register register = new Register();
            register.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone kindly explain how to do this, and if is the correct method? 
PS: im new on C# and OO.

Answer (score 0):

You have a ListViewItem (a Windows Form item) in a non Form class, that is not the way to go, you should have List items instead.
Also you wanna create the EmployeeDAO object only in the Main Form and share it with the Register Form via the constructor of the later. Another way to accomplish this is with the Singleton Pattern.

```
namespace Company
{
    public partial class Register : Form
    {
        EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

        public Register(EmployeeDAO employeeDAO)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.employeeDAO = employeeDAO;
        }

        private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.idEmployee = Convert.ToInt16(this.txtId.Text);
            employee.nameEmployee = this.txtName.Text;
            employeeDAO.insert(employee);

        }

    }
}

namespace Company
{
    class EmployeeDAO
    {
        List<Employee> Items {get; private set;}

        public EmployeeDAO()
        {
            Items = new List<Employee>();
        }

        public void insert(Employee employee)
        {
            Items.Add(employee);
        }
    }
}

namespace Company
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lstEmployee.View = View.Details;
            lstEmployee.FullRowSelect = true;
            lstEmployee.Columns.Add("ID", 150);
            lstEmployee.Columns.Add("Nome", 150);
            employeeDAO = new EmployeeDAO();

        }

        private void InsertEmployeesInListBox()
        {
            lstEmployee.Items.Clear();
            foreach (var item in employeeDAO.Items)
            {
                string[] row = { item.idEmployee.ToString(), item.nameEmployee };
                var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);
                lstEmployee.Items.Add(listViewItem);
            }

        }

        private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Register register = new Register(employeeDAO);
            register.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps !!

Comment: I have some question, why Register need a `EmployeeDAO` object as parameter? and i cant access `Items` on `foreach` in the form `Main`? Its not working yet

Comment: Because EmployeeDAO sets a new List of Employee every time you create a new instance. So instead of creating a new EmployeeDAO with an empty List of Employee every where you pass the first EmployeeDAO you have created to the others classes and reuse the existing List of Employee with data already. In the class EmployeeDAO put public before the declaration List<Employee> Items. You really should learn more before diving into code. If it was helpful my answer please mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea of passing data through forms is to make the Control's Modifiers you will use public so you can use it in another form then you can 
make an object of the second form and code but anyway see these links i hope it will help you

Dulicate [how to pass listview row data into another existing form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899577/how-to-pass-listview-row-data-into-another-existing-form)
[Accessing listview items from another form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038225/accessing-listview-items-from-another-form)
[c# Add listView items from another form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26555667/c-sharp-add-listview-items-from-another-form?rq=1)